# How can I compare data values while looping through my 3D array?

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

I have this array where the first two 2d arrays are of n*n size, but the last array is a 2d array of size * 2.

```
  123  321  13
  231  132  21
  312  213  32
```

Essentially I need to compare the values of the first two arrays and compare them with the values of the smaller 2d array. I keep getting an out of bounds error. The first two arrays values need to be compared with the values of the last array

```
for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  for (int j = 0; j < data[i].length; j++) {
    for (int k = 0; k < data[i][j].length; k++) {
      // I keep getting an out of bounds error here
      if(data[i][j][k] < data[2][j][k]) {
        // do something
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I think the `2` in `data[2][j][k]` is causing the issue. What if `data` has less than 3 elements?

Comment: `i`, `j` and `k` should all be in range, but `2` may not be

Comment: so the last array does have less than 3 elements, so if this is the case, how am I able to work around this?